# How to conditionally return a component in React/Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, react-native

I've used a tool to create React-native components from .svg files. It works well and I can load them using that way.

However, how do I conditionally load them?

I've imported some company logos as such:

```
import Tesla from '../../static/brandlogos/svg/Tesla'
import Amazon from '../../static/brandlogos/svg/Amazon'
import Google from '../../static/brandlogos/svg/Google'
import Facebook from '../../static/brandlogos/svg/Facebook'
import Apple from '../../static/brandlogos/svg/Apple'
```

Indeed, if I invoke the component as such, it works:

```
<Amazon />
```

However, I wish to(of course) conditionally load a component depending on the props this component receives. So, I create a function:

```
 renderLogo (brandName) {
    const Logos = {
        Amazon,
        Facebook,
        Tesla,
        Google,
        Apple
    };

    if (Logos[brandName]) {
        return <Amazon /> // This works!
    }
    if (Logos[brandName]) {
        return Logos[brandName] // This doesn't!
    }
    if (Logos[brandName]) {
        return Logos.Amazon // This also doesn't!
    }
}
```

However, I simply cannot figure out how to create either a map or array to loop through, and render the specific component. If I straight up return the component, of course it works.

But how do I save each "Logo" in an array or map, and conditionally load + return this logo only?

I could, of course, hard code everything but that would be bad.

Comment: `let Component = Logos[brandName]; return <Component />;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do like this

```
if (Logos[brandName]) {
   // Keep in mind the first letter should be capital (i.e. "C" in this case)
   let Comp = Logos[brandName]
   return <Comp />
}
```

Comment: Splendid, it works. Didn't realize you had to reassign it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I think, [this post on Dynamic Component Names with JSX](https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/dynamic-tag-names-in-react-and-jsx-17e366a684e9) answers your question nicely:

```
components = {
    foo: FooComponent,
    bar: BarComponent
};

render() {
   const TagName = this.components[this.props.tag || 'foo'];
   return <TagName />
}
```

In this example you have your tag from the prop - the most typical case for many components.